# How to automatically Filter off error tables using PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery, data-cleaning, m

How can I automatically filter off error tables using Power Query. I have this code that scans through my PDF files to extract the tables that I want in Excel. I want to automatically filter off a CUSTOM column from the unwanted tables that have "Error" as shown in the attached picture.

Your help is greatly appreciated

I tried to filter with PowerQuery but it did not work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI3Jk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh the ribbon, select Home, Remove Rows, Remove Errors.

[image]