# How to remove the Last Error Row in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

[image]

I used
`#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Expanded Data", {"Custom"})`

This works in filtering out all the Errors in the columns but it did not filter out the error on the last row. For whatever reason my last row shows this error as shown in the image attached. I have tried to delete the row but it does not delete. How do I remove this last row that shows "error".

The actual data I need is from Row 1-15. I am not sure how to trap this error so that Power Query can release the results from rows 1-15.
Thanks for your anticipated help

I tried using
`#"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Expanded Data2",1),`
but this did not work. How can I get this last row to be removed. It seems like my data will always have that last error row

Comment: Can you show all your code (copied from advanced editor) and the source data?

Comment: The code is from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76878368/import-various-tables-with-different-formats-from-pdf-into-excel/76878446?noredirect=1#comment135540322_76878446

Comment: Table.RemoveLastN(,1) would ALWAYS remove the last row assuming you referenced the table correctly from the prior step. As to why the RemoveRowsWithErrors is not working you are checking the Custom column which you have not shown. Is that column also an error?

Comment: All the rows at the bottom including the custom column has the error. Try putting a different pdf document in the folder that has the sample pdfs that I attached. You will see that error even if I filter it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me to filter out data from bogus PDFs in save directory

continued from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76878368/import-various-tables-with-different-formats-from-pdf-into-excel/76878446?noredirect=1#comment135540322_76878446)

```
Source2 = Folder.Files("c:\temp\"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source2, each ([Extension] = ".pdf")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Data", each group([Folder Path]&[Name])),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Name", "zName"}}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Data",{"Name","Custom"},{"Name","Custom"}),
#"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Expanded Data", {"Custom"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Errors"[Custom], each Table.ColumnNames(_))), 
#"Expanded Data2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Errors", "Custom", List,List),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Data2",{{"Column4", type date}})  
in  #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: The code ran but I still have the last row that reads ERROR all through the row. When I click "CLOSE and LOAD" into Excel, it shows me an error that says: [DataFormat.Error] We couldn't parse the input provided as Date Value

Comment: I stepped into the code and noticed that the column under the date is showing TEXT instead of a date in one of the cells. Hence, the date could not be changed to a date format. How can I filter only the date out and use the date format for that column?

Comment: Sorry, I am moving on to other activities outside this thread. At this point all the questions seem to be small issues around learning to use PowerQuery basic functions. Best of luck

Comment: can you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78102909/using-try-and-otherwise-in-powerquery