# Using TRY and OTHERWISE in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

How can I Combine these two power query codes (Code 1 and Code 2) using try and otherwise functions. I want either one to run if one encounters a problem. Most of the lines are similar just few that are different.

```
Code 1:

let
    process= (filename)=>
    let Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(filename), [Implementation="1.3"]),
    Page1 = Source{[Id="Page001"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Page1, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Column1", type text}, {"[image]", type text}, type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type datetime}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Test_Date", each Record.Field(#"Changed Type"{1},"test22")),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Column1] = "P123" or [Column1] = "P49" or [Column1] = "P610" or [Column1] = "P75" or [Column1] = "P811" or [Column1] = "11-TEST1" or [Column1] = "11-TEST10" or [Column1] = "11-TEST11" or [Column1] = "11-TEST2" or [Column1] = "11-TEST3" or [Column1] = "11-TEST4" or [Column1] = "11-TEST5" or [Column1] = "11-TEST6" or [Column1] = "11-TEST7" or [Column1] = "11-TEST8" or [Column1] = "11-TEST9")),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Column1", "TEST444"}, {"[image]", "GGG"}, {"test22", "GGG2"}, {"Column4", "GGG3"}, {"Column7", "GGG4"}, {"Column9", "GGG5"}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Column5", "Column6", "Column8", "Column10"})


in  #"Removed Columns",

zSource = Folder.Files("H:\TEST\"),
#"zFiltered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(zSource, each ([Extension] = ".pdf") or ([Extension] = ".PDF")),
#"zAdded Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"zFiltered Rows", "Data", each process([Folder Path]&[Name])),
#"zRenamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"zAdded Custom",{{"Name", "zName"}}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"zRenamed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"zExpanded Data2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"zRenamed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in #"zExpanded Data2"



Code 2:
let
    process= (filename)=>
    let Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(filename), [Implementation="1.3"]),
    Page1 = Source{[Id="Page001"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Page1, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Column1", type text}, {"[image]", type text}, {"test22", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type datetime}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Test_Date", each Record.Field(#"Changed Type"{1},"test22")),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Column1] = "P123" or [Column1] = "P49" or [Column1] = "P610" or [Column1] = "P75" or [Column1] = "P811" or [Column1] = "11-TEST1" or [Column1] = "11-TEST10" or [Column1] = "11-TEST11" or [Column1] = "11-TEST2" or [Column1] = "11-TEST3" or [Column1] = "11-TEST4" or [Column1] = "11-TEST5" or [Column1] = "11-TEST6" or [Column1] = "11-TEST7" or [Column1] = "11-TEST8" or [Column1] = "11-TEST9")),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Column1", "TEST444"}, {"[image]", "GGG"}, {"test22", "GGG2"}, {"Column4", "GGG3"}, {"Column6", "GGG4"}, {"Column8", "GGG5"}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Column5", "Column7", "Column9"})


in  #"Removed Columns",

zSource = Folder.Files("H:\TEST\"),
#"zFiltered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(zSource, each ([Extension] = ".pdf") or ([Extension] = ".PDF")),
#"zAdded Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"zFiltered Rows", "Data", each process([Folder Path]&[Name])),
#"zRenamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"zAdded Custom",{{"Name", "zName"}}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"zRenamed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"zExpanded Data2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"zRenamed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in #"zExpanded Data2"
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate on the example you gave on how to use the Source? How can I save my Query into two different Sources?

Comment: How do I name the queries so that it can call them. I am currently used to creating only one query. I am not sure on how to create multiple queries.

Comment: I tried that and it gave me an error message on the code that generated error when a column is not found

Comment: Sorry, Im giving up. Perhaps someone else can help

Comment: Please can you check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78118088/combining-pdfs-of-slightly-different-formats-using-power-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ml
try #"Code 1" otherwise #"Code 2"
```

will return the results of the `Code 1` query/variable unless it's an error. Otherwise, it will return the results of the `Code 2` query/variable.

So as long as any problems in `Code 1` result in an error (as opposed to a valid list, record, or table that contains an error as one of the values), that should work.

For multiple failover scenarios you can chain several of these statements together.

```ml
try
  Expression1
otherwise try
  Expression2
otherwise try
  Expression3
otherwise
  Expression4
```

For more on error handling, the best article I've seen is https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2020/01/15/4883/power-query-m-primer-part-15-error-handling

Comment: is it possible to try three times like try #"Code 1" otherwise #"Code 2" otherwise #"Code 3"

Comment: Yes, with `try ... otherwise try ... otherwise ...`. I've updated my answer. Please mark as correct if appropriate.