# Modify a working Power Query Code to extract numbers from symbols

Tags: powerquery

The solution presented in the link below works great but I noticed that some of the new PDF files that I have been receiving have symbols in front of the numbers that I am trying to pull out. I have circled an example of the symbols in front and at the end of the number. How do I modify the code presented in the link below to still pull out the numbers regardless of the symbols.

[image]

[Import Various Tables with Different Formats from PDF into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76878368/import-various-tables-with-different-formats-from-pdf-into-excel/76878446?noredirect=1#comment135544812_76878446)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pick the appropriate point in your code, and before subsequent process, transform all the columns to remove the odd characters

```
 #"Columns to transform" = Table.ColumnNames(#"StepNametoProcess"),
 Transforms = List.Transform(#"Columns to transform",(x)=>{x, each Text.Select(_,{"0".."9","a".."z","A".."Z","."})}),
 DoTransform = Table.TransformColumns(StepNametoProcess, Transforms)
```

[image]

EDIT for specific case:

```
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Filtered Rows1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Columns to transform" = Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),
Transforms = List.Transform(#"Columns to transform",(x)=>{x, each Text.Select(_,{"0".."9","a".."z","A".."Z","."})}),
DoTransform = Table.TransformColumns(#"Promoted Headers" , Transforms),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns( DoTransform ,List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),3)),
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have tried the code at various positions but I keep getting an error. Example error is "DataFormat.Error: We couldn't convert to Number. Details: >4494? The error happens at #"Expanded Data2" line

Comment: Do you mean to modify the code above to something like this Text.Select(Text.From,{"0".."9","a".."z","A".."Z","."})}),

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and nice hints...not sure why I am still stuck with DataFormat.Error We couldn't convert to Number. Details: >4494?

Comment: Do we need to put anything below the Source2 section of the code?

Comment: I think your solution is very good but the problem is to find the appropriate point in the code to apply it. I have tried all the various points iteratively but none seems to remove the DataFormat.Error

Comment: Thank you so much...I added the sample pdf to this link with the special symbols...Your previous code works great except with those symbols https://transfer.sh/IxrbQClVRU/NEW_Test_EF2.pdf

Comment: WOW!! You are truly amazing!!! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!